# org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is missing, on Amazon ec2 instance

Tags: maven

I am trying to do

`mvn clean compile package install`

on amazon ec2 but it gives me the following error

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is missing,
```

also in my settings.xml i did uncomment the proxy settings.

help is appreciated.

Comment: No need to run `mvn clean compile package install`. `mvn clean install` will do just fine. Also, post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Still getting the same error
`The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is missing, no dependency information available`
` Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5`

Comment: Did you define an artifact repository containing the plugin?

Comment: Not yet but the strange part is i just cloned the project to my local and it works perfectly.